# Raspberry Pi as smartphone

Tags: screen, touchscreen

How can I transform a Raspberry Pi into a smartphone?

What options as screens do I have?

There are already plenty of answer regarding to batteries in the forum. Like [Battery powered Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8521/battery-powered-raspberry-pi) or [What do I need to know to power from batteries?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-power-from-batteries)

A cell-phone module on the top of it would also be nice, but mainly I have interesting in having a portable Raspberry Pi

Comment: have you seen this? http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/04/man-uses-raspberry-pi-to-build-actual-working-cellphone-for-158/

Comment: Read rob's comment, the persons project is pretty sick. Also, read [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28/how-can-i-determine-if-a-given-touchscreen-is-compatible). Has to do with compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a portable computer, there are a couple of elements you need:

**Screen**
Adafruit's PiTFT is a great  2.8" touchscreen shield and can even be bought with a fitting PiBow case.

**Keyboard**
You can buy micro keyboards that have a laptop trackpad inbuilt, they're wireless too.

**Battery**
While you could use a LiPo and a regulator, it's much easier to use a portable power bank or similar - they will come much closer to providing the ~1A the Pi needs.

That's the main bits, internet could be a little trickier but you could throw in a nano WiFi dongle.

Comment: If you do go with a power bank, make sure it actually bumps the voltage up to 5v - many don't since devices will charge just fine off of 4v.